# Some MongoDB questions

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to MongoDB and Meteor. I have checked the official docs but seems they didn't do good job. Here I have couple of questions.

The structure is as follows.

```
{
    _id:"127467812649871246",
    "name":"Disha",
    "last_name":"shukla",
    "members":
     [
        {
           name:"xyz"
        },
       {
           name:"abc"
       }
     ],
     "user":"premium"

}
```

1] How to insert data in particular field when the data is already exists by referring the record ID ? In this case, insert a new member in "Members"

2] In some cases there wont be "user":"premium" field. Because I wont insert at first time.  How do I check if that field is exists if I have inserted for some document ?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) command is used to insert data into an existing array in MongoDB. And [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is used to check whether a field exists in a collection. Go to the links to find more.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use update by some selector, for example by name 
CollectionName.update({name:"Disha"}, {$push: {members: {name: "new"}}})

2) If you want to check if the field exists use this 
CollectionName.find({user: {$exists:true}}).
If you want to check if user is premium 
CollectionName.find({user: "premium"}).
If you want to check both:
CollectionName.find({$and: [{user: {$exists:true}}, {user: "premium"}]})